# How to write test cases for assignment

Tags: python, testing

The part of my assignment is to create tests for each function. This ones kinda long but I am so confused. I put a link below this function so you can see how it looks like
first code is extremely long because.

```
def load_profiles(profiles_file, person_to_friends, person_to_networks):
    '''(file, dict of {str : list of strs}, dict of {str : list of strs}) -> NoneType
    Update person to friends and person to networks dictionaries to include
    the data in open file.'''

    # for updating person_to_friends dict
    update_p_to_f(profiles_file, person_to_friends)
    update_p_to_n(profiles_file, person_to_networks)
```

heres the whole code: http://shrib.com/8EF4E8Z3, I tested it through mainblock and it works. 
This is the text file(profiles_file) we were provided that we are using to convert them :
http://shrib.com/zI61fmNP

How do I run test cases for this through nose, what kinda of test outcomes are there? Or am I not being specific enough?

import nose
import a3_functions

def test_load_profiles_

if **name** == '**main**':
    nose.runmodule()
I went that far then I didn't know what I can test for the function.

Comment: Yes you are not being specific enough. Test cases are examples of data which could be entered into your program, you have to see if your output is correct and your program does not fail. To run test cases you can simply create some files such as the `profiles_file` and run your program with them. See if it works. Make different types of files with different data and see if they all work. Its hard to see what test cases you should run when we know nothing about the data.

Comment: Ohh, its because there is so much data i cant copy it all here.. unless I actually go into detail 1 on 1 with them . And people wuldnt bother reading it. so testing these type of data u have to create ur own texts?

Comment: Yes, create your own files, or whatever input your program accepts. Try and use almost every different type of thing you can think of to see if your program works for all cases.

Comment: What is the minimal amount of test cases that is reasonable, since I dont know the obvious ones. I dont think 1 is enough but I dont think I need like 7, or 8.

Comment: Wait, if I create my own text then how do i write the code. 

import nose
import a3_functions #the file name of where my functions def are

def test_load_profiles():
    assert a3_functions.load_profiles(profiles_file, person_to_friends, person_to_networks)????
    




if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.runmodule()
    
how does it know im using a text file that I made myself... omgosh this is so confusing

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that last post, it's hard to read in a comment like that.  What do you mean by how does it know im using a text file that I made myself... a computer doesn't need to know that. It doesn't matter who made the file.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ and provide more background on what you are trying to do.  What does "tests for every function" mean?  Unit tests?

Comment: Mkays, I editteed it and provided the actual codes maybethat will make it better. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume the code you wrote so far is in a module called "mycode".

Write a new module called testmycode. (i.e. create a python file called testmycode.py)

In there, import the module you want to test (mycode)

Write a function called testupdate().

In that function, first write a text file (with file.write) that you expect to be valid. Then let update_p_to_f update it. Verify that it did what you expect, using assert. This is a test for reading a text file.

Then you can write a second function called testupdate_write(), where you let your code write to a file -- then verify that what it wrote is correct.

To run the tests, use (on the commandline)

```
 nosetests -sx testmycode.py
```

Which will load testmycode and run all functions it finds there that start with test.

Comment: so since it takes txt files as parameter does this mean i have to create diff text files just to test it?

Comment: if by 'diff' you mean different, yes. The idea is to cover various aspects of the function you want to test, to make sure every line of code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to test both the overall output of your program is correct, and that individual parts of your program are correct.

- @j13r has already covered how to test the overall correctness of your program for a full run.
- You mention that you have four helper functions. You can write tests for these separately.

Testing smaller pieces of your code is helpful because you can test each piece in more numerous and more specific ways than if you only test the whole thing.

The [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) module is a framework for performing tests.

Comment: You can use nose for running only individual tests: nosetests -sx testmycode.py:testupdate

Comment: Wait so I have to write a seperate file for helper functions as well?  Or can I just include that all under the one function it goes under.